# Mistakenly deleted android-support-appcompat-v7 from sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I have mistakenly deleted android-support-appcompat-v7 from sdk. I hoped that the sdk manager would see it and asked me an update on extras->Android support Library but no.

What can I do now please to reinstall android-support-appcompat-v7 into my android-sdk?

Comment: Delete and then download again using the SDK manager.

Comment: That's the solution.thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Android SDK Manager.
2. Select the checkboxes of the parts of the SDK you want to delete.
3. Click Delete.
4. Select the checkboxes of the parts of the SDK you want to install.
5. Click Install.